# Multi level Gravity Wheel

Tags: gravity, microgravity, spacecraft, artificial-gravity

If you had a space structure in the form of a disk shape. Inside it would have rooms and hall ways connecting the rooms. Each hall is a continues ring so if you walk in one direction in a hall you will end up where you started.

In this example we have 3 halls inner mid and outer. If the structure is spinning at a speed that the mid hallway would have 1G would the inner hallway and outer hallway also have 1G? Or will each point in the structure experience a different g-force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the G-force of the middle hallway was 1G would the person on the inner and outer halls also be experiencing 1G?

If the levels are spinning at the same rate (e.g. 4 times per minute) no.  For a given rate of rotation, the centripetal force increases in a linear way as you move further from, or closer to, the center.  Twice is far from the center, leads to twice the force.

If they are spinning independently of each other, possibly.

Comment: All hallways are internal structure of the solid spinning disk. The hallways would not spin as they would be part of the disk.

Comment: any math to the difference from the distances withinside a spinning disk?

Comment: See [Centripetal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) for more details.